# Fixing the cause from a Socket Exception in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, network-programming

I'm creating a small server for multiple winform client connecting to it over the internet.
The following code works when it is set to the local address:

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(9000);
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    int counter = 0;

    serverSocket.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
    counter = 0;
    while ((true))
    {
        counter += 1;
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;

        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

        clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

        broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

        Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
        handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
        client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
    }

    clientSocket.Close();
    serverSocket.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Winform Client:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
    string readData = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readData = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
        msg();
        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9000);
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox3.Text + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
        ctThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Those piece of code works fine talking to each other over the network.
But when I decide to change this line of code

`clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9000);` 
to 
`clientSocket.Connect("81.62.126.41", 9000);`

for my ip address it gives me the following SocketException:

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

So some things I have tried. Port forwarding port 9000 because I am behind my router. Creating inbound and outbound rules for port 9000. And I have gone to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ while my server is running and the website can in fact see my service.

Anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?

Here's a pic of netstat when the server is running. Thought it might be helpful.
[image]

Comment: Based on your description, something is blocking IP packets to or from your host. Try using Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor to view the packets on your host, it should point you in the direction of where the packets are being filtered.

Comment: @William No Idea what that is, but I'll test it out.

Comment: @William I'm using Wireshark and I've been able to capture the package and info I want but I have no idea what I'm suppose to look for.

Comment: Capture packets in a scenario that works properly, this will show you want a successful TCP connection looks like. Then capture packets on both the server and client in a scenario that fails, compare the results against the working set and you should be able to see which side is being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue.

1. If you change only one string in your code and it stops working double-check the tools you're using. Some internal proxys could allow/disallow you to communicate with internal (127.0.0.1) or external ip.
2. Check the same URL in your browser 127.0.0.1:9000 and 81.62.126.41:9000. If it doesn't open for the second case then issue in your firewall or setting up your server to be able for external access, not in your code.
3. Your exception means that something wrong with your server: you could try open `http://81.62.12.32/` and open `http://81.62.126.41:9000/` and you will see two different errors.

Conclusion: Issue is not in your code. It's in your web server settings or in firewall set up.